# Isolate Liferay access to frontend and REST URL's

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, liferay-7

I have a Liferay instance running on a URL like `example.org/app`. This instance does have a REST API that would normally be running under `example.org/app/o/restpath`.

The way the server running this instance is that the frontend is accessible without restrictions from the outside, however the REST API is only accessible from the inside the network under a URL like `example.org/rest`.

I need to make sure that it is impossible to access the REST API with `example.org/app`. I should also be impossible to access the frontend with `example.org/rest`. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: /o is the OSGi container's context, in which various applications are mapped. Among them your own REST endpoints, but also some of Liferay's built-in features. In `/o/restpath`, `restpath` is custom to you, and it should be easy to cover in ACL in a reverse proxy, even based on source IPs. On top, you should of course have proper authentication for any REST call

Comment: So that's what the /o ist for! So I it not possible for something behind /o/a to accidently make a request to /o/b?

Comment: well, it's code running there. Any code running on your server has access to the API and doesn't need to go through HTTP to do stuff. And, unless it's a bug, which code "accidentally" makes a request to a random resource? I'd assume that most of the time it's deliberate. But, as I said: HTTP is not required if you're running within the server anyways.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of ways of doing that, the best one will depend on your stack, preferences and abilities.

A reverse proxy is the first that comes to mind, bearing in mind that is is normally better if your app has control of who can access it. So a wrapper  or a filter checking who is accessing would help. But even then, is the filter to be put on the main application or on your module? That is an evaluation that needs to come from you.

You can also combine the proxy strategy, with a filter, just in case one day you are tuning up your proxy and let something through. You can also decide change your proxy server too..

Or your company already have a proxy that enables traffic going out, and would be easier if that proxy was to have access...

Your servlet contained might also be able to provide such control, so you do not actually need a proxy.

Although I would feel more comfortable if that kind of feature was in the application layer itself, like a wrapper for your component and that wrapper provides the service, a filter, or even a method in in the entry-point, while the others are just extra and to reduce load.

Some companies have networks devices that go up several layers of the network stack, those have lots of potential to help here too, IDS would be able to provide alarms, triggers and such...
As it stands, one would need more information to help you more, even in what you mean by "ensure" ( how far this assurance need to go, like are you thinking about passwords, certificates, IDS, or a simple approach like the mentioned ones ), but I guess that covers it.